# Getting type name of boxed object

Tags: c#

How can I get the type name (in string) of instance boxed in object?
I can't use is or as operators.
For example:

```
    object a= student1; //student1 is instance of Student class
```

Next I will get it object in another library, where no Student class inside and no reference.
And I need something like this:

```
string typeName=GetTypeNameInsideObject(obj1)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
a.GetType().Name
```